# Uso de Malloc en C

Tags: c

Soy nueva en esto y no me queda claro **cuándo** debo usar malloc y cuándo no es necesario.

Estoy siguiendo un curso online y en algunos ejercicios pide que "de usar malloc, se libere la memoria al terminar", pero como pude resolverlos sin malloc, no termino de entender cuál sería la diferencia entre que el programa se escriba con malloc y sin malloc.

Gracias!

Comment: Cuando usas punteros éstos tienen que inicializarse apuntando a algún lugar. O bien los inicializas apuntando a otra variable, o bien tienes que usar malloc() para reservar memoria a la que apuntar. Si usas otra variable, el problema suele ser que esa variable tiene un tamaño prefijado (un array). Cuando necesitas que el tamaño se decida en tiempo de ejecución, necesitarás usar malloc(). También cuando no puedes tener creadas de antemano las variables porque no sabes cuántas van a ser. Para más detalles habría que ver tu código "sin malloc" a ver si es correcto,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para simplificar diremos que en todo programa existen dos regiones bien diferenciadas de memoria:

- La pila
- El montón

La pila, o stack, es una región de memoria de tamaño fijo que se reserva al ejecutar el programa. La pila es utilizada por el programa para almacenar variables locales y para saber a qué punto del código debe volver cuando termina de ejecutar una función.

El montón representa la memoria de tu equipo. Es un espacio de memoria enorme donde los diferentes programas pueden almacenar información de cualquier tipo.

Cuando tu declaras variables en tu programa, generalmente se hace uso de la pila. Es decir, ante la siguiente instrucción:

```
int a = 1, b = 2;
```

El programa ocupará 4 bytes para la variable `a` y otros 4 para la variable `b`.

La pila es perfecta para variables pequeñas, puesto que al ser una región de memoria gestionada por la aplicación, las variables son automáticamente eliminadas cuando salen de ámbito.

Sin embargo, la pila no es perfecta. Tiene ciertas restricciones a tener en cuenta:

- No es una región demasiado grande. Si te dedicas a almacenar objetos de gran tamaño se llenará y el programa no podrá funcionar
- Al tratarse de una pila, la información se destruye en orden inverso al que se añadió a la misma. Es complicado gestionar variables de ámbito global

Cuando necesitas almacenar información de caracter dinámico, es decir, que no puedes conocer en tiempo de compilación (una agenda de direcciones, una serie de registros que se encuentran almacenados en archivos, ...), entonces es preferible moverte al montón.

El problema que tiene el montón es que tienes que encargarte de gestionar el ciclo de vida de lo que ahí almacenes. A cambio te ofrece libertad de movimientos.

Por poner ejemplos concretos:

Un array de 5 enteros se podría crear perfectamente en la pila:

```
int array[5];
```

Sin embargo, un array de 1000 elementos sería preferible crearlo en el montón:

```
int* array = (int*)malloc(1000 * sizeof(int));
```

Por otro lado, un array de un número indeterminado de elementos también podría ser preferible ubicarlo en el montón:

```
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
int * array = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
```

La memoria, una vez reservada, puede utilizarse para almacenar información sin importar su origen. El acceso a esa memoria se realizará de la misma forma.

Ahora bien, como hemos dicho antes, somos responsables de gestionar la memoria que reservamos en el montón. Esto quiere decir que debemos liberar la memoria que ya no sea necesaria. Para esta tarea disponemos de la función `free`:

```
free(array); // Libera la memoria reservada por malloc
```

Para más información acerca del funcionamiento de la pila o del montón, te sugiero navegar por Internet

Comment: Muy buena explicación. Me gustaría añadir la importancia de 2 funciones más: `realloc()` permite reasignar memoria a la ya creada dinámicamente con `malloc()` y poder ampliar la región de memoria creada. Y la otra función importante al trabajar con asignaciones dinámicas de memoria es `free()`. Esta función sirve para liberar la memoria asignada y es de uso recomendado (por no decir imperativo) cuando trabajes con este tipo de metodología. En internet como dice el gran @eferion tienes información a raudales con ejemplo, definiciones, etc.

Comment: @Londo cierto, me centré en el tema de la pila y el montón y se me pasó lo del `free`. Lo de `realloc` no pensaba comentarlo para no elaborar una respuesta excesivamente larga